# Django store instances in cache

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached, instances

Is it bad to store django instances or querysets directly in the cache ?
For example I want to store 10 "articles" (supposing they won't change in the next days) so that users can navigate between them without hitting the database (like one could do with angular).
Also is there a maximum size capacity for the cache ?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be bad to store django instances/querysets directly in the cache.  Django provides [serialization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/) utility to allow you to easily convert instances/querysets to a format then deasieralize that data into django objects.

Memcache supports having a cluster of nodes that appear as if they are a single instance.

http://memcached.org/about

This should let you add more servers if you need to expand the capacity of  the cache